# Jenkins Build fails after successful build deployment

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins

After the successful deployment the build fails due to this error every time. Please help me.

Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 8 22:04:49 UTC 2013 x86_64 GNU/Linux

```
FATAL: Remote call on slave1 failed

java.io.IOException: Remote call on slave1 failed
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:723)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher.kill(Launcher.java:887)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:585)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1665)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:246)
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError
    at hudson.util.ProcessTree$UnixReflection.<clinit>(ProcessTree.java:618)
    at hudson.util.ProcessTree$UnixProcess.kill(ProcessTree.java:552)
    at hudson.util.ProcessTree$UnixProcess.killRecursively(ProcessTree.java:572)
    at hudson.util.ProcessTree$Unix.killAll(ProcessTree.java:496)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher$KillTask.call(Launcher.java:899)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher$KillTask.call(Launcher.java:890)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.UNIXProcess.destroyProcess(int)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2109)
    at hudson.util.ProcessTree$UnixReflection.<clinit>(ProcessTree.java:607)
    ... 13 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging this bug report: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-21341

It seems you are running the JDK version 1.8, am I right?

If so, you might want to downgrade to 1.7 until Jenkins is made compatible.

Comment: yes you are correct .i will try to downgrade and then try it.Thanks

Comment: May I ask how you solved this problem finally? Because I'm having the exact same issue.

Comment: Upgrading the master to Jenkins 1.610 solved the problem, no need to downgrade the client to Java 1.7. You could go higher, 1.610 was a version which still runs on Java 1.6 which we have on the master.